# how to return the newly created thumb image name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter.I need to resize image in a site and I'm using the following code.

```
function resizeImage($imgName)
{

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = "/var/www/folder/backgroundimages/".$imgName;
        $config['new_image'] = "/var/www/folder/backgroundimages/thumb/".$imgName;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 150;
        $config['height'] = 120;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

}
```

This works fine and the thumb will be created with a name imagename_thumb.jpg.

What I want is to return the name of the newly created thumb image's name from this function.
How can this be done ?

Comment: You already have image name in `$imgName`. Don't you ?

Comment: $imgName is the name of the original image and not thumb image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resize function will save the thumb as `mypic_thumb.jpg`

> The above code tells the image_resize function to look for an image called mypic.jpg located in the source_image folder, then create a thumbnail that is 75 X 50 pixels using the GD2 image_library. Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the thumb will be as close to the target width and height as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio. The thumbnail will be called mypic_thumb.jpg

so you can return

```
 $imgDetailArray=explode('.',$imgName)
 $thumbimgname=$imgDetailArray[0].'_thumb';
  return $thumbimgname.'.'.$imgDetailArray[1]
```

"OR"

pass rawimage as parameters in resize function...

```
 function resizeImage($imgName,$rawimage)
 {
   .......
```

you can use `$this->upload->data()` to get file details if you  are  uploading the file and resizing it...[docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) here

Comment: $imgName is mypic.jpg isn't it ? so $thumbimgname=$imgName.'_thumb';
  return $thumbimgname  
will return mypic.jpg_thumb . isn't it ?

Comment: yes .. sorry my bad.... you can explode the it with '.' abd extract the filename witout extension... and add _thumb to the imagename.,..

Comment: yea.I tired that.but was blocked when an image came with "." in its name.So the exploding doesn't worked.

Comment: then u can use `$this->upload->data()` when uploading the file to get tehe files details and pass to to resize function... you can tyr it out..

Answer (score 0):

You have given the image name as `$imgName`. Then why do you want the name?

you can access that thumb image from the location,

```
/var/www/folder/backgroundimages/thumb/$imgName
```

Comment: actually its renaming the thumb image by adding _thumb at the end.And so it can be accessed by /var/www/folder/backgroundimages/thumb/$imgName

Answer (score 0):

I use `$config['thumb_marker'] = "";` in the configuration  to remove the **_thumb** and for more details check CodeIgniter’s image manipulation class
documentation [here](http://localhost/mitspec2/Crud/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=thumbnail#processing-an-image).